# analytical form of beta function, what is wrong about this?

Tags: calculus, beta-function

This has to be a really stupid question, but here it goes:

$$
\int_0^1 t^{x-1} (1 -t)^{y-1} dt= \int_0^1 t^{x-1} dt- \int_0^1 t^{x+y-2} dt=
$$

$$
\frac{t^x}{x} |^1_0 + \frac{t^{x+y-1}}{x+y-1} |^1_0 = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x+y-1}
$$

Something extremely obvious has to be going on, since I never see this closed form,  but I don't see what exactly.

Comment: how have you aparted the term $$t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}$$? this is impossible

Comment: In general $(a+b)^{z}\neq a^z+b^z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong??

This:

$$\large \boxed{t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} \color{red}{\neq} t^{x-1} - t^{x-1}\cdot t^{y-1}}$$

Comment: of course. God, I was blind.

Comment: @elelias lol!$~~~$

Comment: I swear some days...